# Celery monitoring with SQS broker

Tags: celery, airflow, amazon-sqs

We are using Airflow(1.10.3) with Celery executor(4.1.1 (latentcall)) and broker SQS. While debugging an issue we tried our hands on celery CLI and found out that SQS broker is not supported for any of the inspect commands or monitoring tool eg. Flower.

Is there any way we can monitor the tasks or events on celery workers?

We have tried the celery monitor as follows:

```
celery events -b sqs://
```

But it shows no worker discovered and no tasks selected.
The `celery inspect` command help page shows:

> Availability: RabbitMQ (AMQP) and Redis transports.

Please let me know if I am missing something or is it even possible to monitor celery workers with SQS.

Answer (score 3):

SQS transport does not provide support for monitoring/inspection (this is the main reason why I do not use it)... According to the [latest documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html) Redis and RabbitMQ are the only broker types that have support for monitoring/inspection and remote control.