# Is every Kombu "transport" a valid Celery "broker"? What's the relation between the two concepts?

Tags: celery, kombu

In particular, I'd like to know is there a 1:1 relationship between a Celery ["broker"](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/getting-started/brokers/index.html) and a Kombu ["transport"](http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/latest/introduction.html#transport-comparison)?

Also, assuming a direct relationship, is there also a direct relationship between a Celery "brokers" support for "Monitoring" and "Remote Control" and the Kombu "transport"?

Put another way, **is every Kombu "transport" a valid Celery "broker" and how can I tell whether a Celery "broker" supports "Monitoring" and/or "Remote Control" by code inspection alone** or even via PDB.

---

### Investigation so far

I have read the documentation, but became suspicious when I discovered [this article using the filesystem Kombu transport for Celery](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/07/03/simple-celery-setup/). This suspicion deepened when I saw that the list of supported brokers hadn't been updated since 2016.

I also found [this stackoverflow question: "celery monitoring with sqs broker"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58338090/celery-monitoring-with-sqs-broker) which while recent, seems to rely heavily on the documentation which may be out of date.

Turning to code inspection I can't spot any Kombu transport *specific* code in Celery which would implement or toggle monitoring or remote control, and these terms don't seem to appear in [Kombu's list of supported transports](http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/latest/introduction.html#transport-comparison).

Also Kombu seems to do a really good job of encapsulating away the transport from Celery and implementing virtual transports to support features those transports wouldn't otherwise support. I wonder if this clever encapsulation has essentially made Celery's documentation on broker support outdated, and one transport is as good as another to Celery (apart from perhaps performance).

I also did a high level scan of Celery's change notes and Github Issues and nothing leapt out at me there either.

### Why?

At least while we're experimenting being able to use in-memory or filesystem brokers (if it is possible to use those transports like that) would be very advantageous while we evaluated Celery. If that works it'd be interesting to also test the monitoring and remote control capabilities of Celery while we're at it.

We currently use SQS for a message queue, and I'd very much like to use Celery to encapsulate away from SQS, give us a bit more freedom and testability. It'd be nice to know if the SQS broker supports more than is documented.

My next step will be to just try it and see, but I'd very much like to understand what's going on underneath the hood, whether or not the above works.

**Thanks for any help!**

Answer (score -1):

I believe every Kombu "transport" is a valid broker option.

But, as you already mentioned, they (transports) do not support all features (monitoring, remote control). And for that reason I do not use SQS even though I would very much love to do so... I wish I could use AWS AMQ with Celery.